# anchor tag inside a div. When div click it page should redirect to one page and if anchor click the page should redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an one div inside that an anchor tag like this.

```
<div onclick="page reddirec to one location"  style="height:200px;width:200px"><a href="http://www.google.com" >text</a></div>
```

Here div having height and width 200px each and also onclick the div the page should redirect to one location. But also there is an anchor tag inside this div but onclick this anchor tag the page should redirect to another location. Is it possible to implement this in html or by using the javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('a')){
        //this will stop event bubbling and will open the href of the anchor
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else{
        location.href = "anotherUrl";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE 9, Firefox 11, and Google Chrome 18:

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.yahoo.com'" style="height:200px;width:200px;background-color:Red;">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" >text</a>
</div>
```